# FD step size on individual design variables

Tags: openmdao

I'm a little bit confused about how to specify FD step sizes on the individual design variables. In the old OpenMDAO it was possible to specify the step size when adding the desvar. In the new version add_desvar does not have this argument, so I tried to set it on the IndepVarComp's fd_options, which didn't work either. It is not so intuitive to me that I have to set it on the downstream component. But in case I had to do it this way, how would I set it on each individual param at setup time? I'm probably missing something, but could you please let me know how to to it on the below example where I'm trying to set the step size of `prob.root.sub.p1` with `force_fd` on the whole problem.

```
from openmdao.api import Component, Group, Problem, IndepVarComp

class MyComp(Component):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyComp, self).__init__()

        # Params
        self.add_param('x1', 3.0, step_size = 1e-2)
        self.add_param('x2', 3.0)

        # Unknowns
        self.add_output('y', 5.5)

    def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
        """ Doesn't do much. """
        unknowns['y'] = 7.0*params['x1']**2 + 7.0*params['x2']**2

prob = Problem()
prob.root = Group()
sub = prob.root.add('sub', Group())
comp = prob.root.add('comp', MyComp())
p1 = sub.add('p1', IndepVarComp([('x1', 3.0), ('x2', 3.0)]))

# this has no effect
prob.root.sub.p1.fd_options['step_size'] = 1.0e-1



prob.root.connect('sub.p1.x1', 'comp.x1')
prob.root.connect('sub.p1.x2', 'comp.x2')

prob.root.fd_options['force_fd'] = True 

prob.setup(check=False)
prob.run()

J = prob.calc_gradient(['sub.p1.x1', 'sub.p1.x2'], ['comp.y'], return_format='dict')

print J
```

If I print mydict in `System.fd_jacobian` and the step size I see:

```
('mydict', {'shape': 1, 'step_size': 0.01, 'pathname': 'comp.x1', 'val': 3.0, 'promoted_name': 'comp.x1', 'top_promoted_name': 'comp.x1', 'size': 1})
('FD', 'comp.x1', 0.01)
('mydict', {'val': 3.0, 'promoted_name': 'comp.x2', 'shape': 1, 'pathname': 'comp.x2', 'top_promoted_name': 'comp.x2', 'size': 1})
('FD', 'comp.x2', 1e-06)

{'comp.y': {'sub.p1.x1': array([[ 42.07]]), 'sub.p1.x2': array([[ 42.000007]])}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are right though, we used to also have it on the old `add_parameter`call (the equivalent of `add_desvar` now) in classic OpenMDAO, and we haven't re-implemented that yet, so it looks like we still need to do this.

In the mean time, the only way to control stepsize at the var level is to set `step_size` in the downstream target of the `IndepVarComp` of the connection, which you do with `x1` in your example. It's a workaround that will accomplish what you want, but it is a little nonintuitive and possibly tedious for broadcast connections unfortunately.